# How do I find all cut vertices (aka articulation points) in a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given a connected graph $G = (V,E)$, we say that a vertex $v \in V$ is a *cut vertex* of $G$ if the removal of $v$ from $G$ causes $G$ to become disconnected.

How can I find **all** cut vertices of a given graph using *Mathematica*? Apparently there was an [`ArticulationVertices` function in *Combinatorica*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/ArticulationVertices.html), which the docs say has been superseded by [`FindVertexCut`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindVertexCut.html?q=FindVertexCut). However, this new function only finds *one* cut vertex (if one exists), where the old one found *all* of them.

I should note that I'm working with some code that uses native `Graph` objects, and would prefer not to have to deal with `` Combinatorica`Graph ``s if possible.

Comment: `FindVertexCut` returns a _list_ of vertices representing smallest cut, and you want to find all smallest or all possible?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I want to find a list of *all* (individual) cut vertices of a graph. I'm not interested in vertex cuts of size greater than 1.

Answer (score 4):

[IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) has the function `IGArticulationPoints`.

```
g = PathGraph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
IGArticulationPoints[g]
(* {3, 2} *)
```

---

Speed comparison with `KVertexConnectedComponents[g,2]` for tiny and huge graphs. The timings are for IGraph/M 0.1.5.

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "CondensedMatterCollaborations2005"}];

{VertexCount[g], EdgeCount[g]}
(* {40421, 175692} *)

RepeatedTiming[IGArticulationPoints[g];, 2]
(* {0.064, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[KVertexConnectedComponents[g, 2];, 2]
(* {0.13, Null} *)

g = PathGraph@Range[10];

RepeatedTiming[IGArticulationPoints[g];, 2]
(* {0.000078, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[KVertexConnectedComponents[g, 2];, 2]
(* {7.0*10^-6, Null} *)
```

Comment: A note on performance: in IGraph/M 0.1.5 (not yet released) this takes about the same amount of time as `KVertexConnectedComponents[g,2]` alone, for not too small graphs.  In the current release it might be a bit slower, I haven't tried.

Answer (score 3):

One (not particularly efficient) way that occurs to me is to first find the biconnected components of a graph `g`, for which there is a built-in function (`KVertexConnectedComponents`). Then, use the fact that a vertex is a cut vertex if and only if it appears in two biconnected components.

```
components = KVertexConnectedComponents[g, 2];
cutVertices = Flatten[Intersection @@@ Subsets[components, {2}]];
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a bad solution to me.

Comment: You can improve the performance by pre-sorting the components, i.e. `components = Sort /@ KVertexConnectedComponents[g, 2]`.